# Mining hardware mega thread question

Tags: discussion

What are people's thoughts of starting a mining hardware comparison mega thread question? Something that would have to be curated, but would allow for people to comment or answer what h/s they get using what hardware and software and possibly power consumption if known? Appropriate? Or better left to a getmonero forum thread or something?

Comment: Sounds like useful information but curation over time may prove difficult as available mining software is optimized or abandoned and new hardware becomes available.

Answer (score 5):

I fear the Stack Exchange Q&A format is not best suited for creating such a thread. First of all it will not be a question at all, and also it will not cover a specific problem and I would probably vote to close it as **too broad**:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

**TL;DR** In my eyes it will lead to a [type of thread which should be avoided to ask](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score -5):

I believe this would be a great wiki post here on moneroSE. We can post hardware and maybe even software configs for different setups.